# Why use "use function" in php script?

Tags: php

I was reading the source code of Slim and I see in several files the use of :

```
use function json_encode;
use function trim;
...
```

What is the purpose of this declaration?

Thanks

Comment: For example in [slim code] (https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/4.x/Slim/Middleware/BodyParsingMiddleware.php)

Comment: see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba : Yes I know this. But why declare native PHP function ? (trim, json_decode, ) ... it's not related to namespaces ...

Comment: You will also see some code which always calls these with `\trim` or `\json_encode`, the effect is to define which namespace the functions are so that PHP doesn't have to search for them.

Comment: @ShadeBob in Slim source: namespace Slim\Middleware; use function explode; ... etc.

Comment: Ok. Find the Answer ... Is for [opcode optimization](https://dev.to/codeurm/php-tips-how-to-use-optimized-built-it-functions-32be).

Comment: @ShadeBob  if you answer your question, i'll op-vote that too :)  thks.  Now on to the PhpStorm community forums for me.

Comment: @ShadeBob The difference in execution time is within the statistical error. Count the alleged "savings" on these several functions in the script. On my Pentium M (!)  testing time from the given website for 10k loop  is 0.02s for both versions in PHP7.4.4. The reason for using the use function for built-in functions is the desire to introduce a little order into the chaos of PHP and strictly define what we can use as part of a specific namespace and which we do not use.